# Mysql having a table reference itself

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'd like to do is for a gaming application I need to search for my non player characters and they have a field called target_id that stores the id of whatever they are chasing.

```
given:
table mobs with fields and some example data
id   x   y   target_id
1    1   1   2
2    3   3   1
```

I would like to return the following data with a query

```
id   x   y   target_id target_x target_y
1    1   1   2         3        3
2    3   3   1         1        1
```

This is what I tried but it has syntax errors

```
SELECT id,x,y,target_id, target.x, target.y FROM mobs LEFT JOIN mobs AS target ON      target_id=id FROM mobs WHERE 1
```

Comment: Remove the seconds 'FROM mobs' - and the last WHERE

Comment: @jcho360 - No, that's not it, the `ON` is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you have a `WHERE 1` or the second `FROM`, but I believe that this is what you want:

```
SELECT M.id, M.x, M.y, M.target_id, T.x, T.y 
FROM mobs AS M
LEFT JOIN mobs AS T 
ON M.target_id = T.id
```

In the future, you should post your table definition, and the expected result so your question is more clear.

Comment: I didn't post the actual table definition because my tables are for a gaming application so they have about 70 fields.

Comment: @Shawn - Wee don't need your whole table definition, just the necessary fields to understand your problem and think how to solve it. In this case, you could've posted your table and the columns `id, target_id, x, y` for example

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax as far as I know is:

```
SELECT mobs.id, mobs.x, mobs.y, mobs.target_id, target.x, target.y 
FROM mobs 
LEFT JOIN mobs AS target 
ON      mobs.target_id = target.id
```

You've already specified the 'FROM' by saying 'JOIN' and you don't need a WHERE when you don't need to filter any rows

Edit: sorry I didn't put the aliases in - you need to make sure the last part (and the fields in the select) have which tables you want to target - remember, saying target_id doesn't mean much if you have two tables in the query with the same column name. You will get an ambiguity error otherwise. I've added the aliases to the query

Comment: You have ambiguous columns there, you need to add a prefix to those.

Comment: yeah this basic idea worked all the fields need to be prefixed so they aren't ambiguous... thanks for the quick response.